# Append two different files by lines

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, paste

I have two files, `file1` and `file2`, with different data inside of each line, and want to add every line in `file2` to the end of every line in `file1`.

Like this:

file1 contains:

```
1
2
3
```

file2 contains:

```
a
b
c
```

And the result must be:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

There is no way to use the `paste` command :( Only - `sed`, `awk`, `cat`, `grep`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you use `paste`?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'R file2' file1 | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' > file3
```

This uses two invocations of sed. The first appends each line of file2 to each line of file1. The second: reads two lines at a time and replaces the newline between them with a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} {print a[FNR], $0}' file1 file2
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste is the right tool and both solutions here above are probably more efficient. I just wanted to add a "pure bash" version:

```
$ while read r1 <&3 && read r2 <&4 ; do echo "$r1 $r2" >> out ; done 3<file1 4<file2
```

Answer (score 0):

how about `cat` with `pr`

```
$ cat file1 file2 | pr -2ts' '

1 a
2 b
3 c
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk solution that reads for each line the of `file1` the next line of `file2`, then prints them both:

```
 awk '{getline var < "file2"; print $0, var}' file1
```